# How to map .so files to source files in gdb

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I have core dump file. when I try to open in gdb. I am able to see the backtrace (with address and its corresponding functions) but the corresponding function in mapped to .so files not to source.

bt looks like this

```
#0  0xf611b39c in xxFun () from /lib/libxx.so.0

$file /lib/libtxx.so.0
/lib/libtxx.so.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Able to display symbols using nm!

Queries:-
1) How can I map this .so files to source files
2) I am not able to display info locals/args. How can I get these data?

When I try to display

```
#info locals
No symbol table info available.
#info args
No symbol table info available.
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: If you build the .so file yourself, build it again in debug mode (that is, use at least `-g` compilation flag). If not, you need to get the debug version (or the sources to build one) from the library maintainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly as "n.m." commented, you need libxx.so built with debug info (usualy `-g` switch at compile time).

That will provide both address to source mapping, and `info locals`, `args`, etc.

Comment: @n.m and @Employed Russian. Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I need to build it with debug mode and use *.so.debug file instead of *.so files. But the *.so files show, it is not striped. that is the only things which is weird.